# Accessing a class created within another class

Tags: php, oop

I have a `page` class for my web page.  When this is called, it creates a new `user`.  This allows me to check if there is a user logged in. Here is the construct method from the `page` class:

```
public function __construct() {
    // check user is logged in
    require 'classes/user.class.php';
    $user = new user();
    if(!$user->isLoggedIn()) {
        // user is not logged in
        // load login page
    }
    else {
        // user is logged in
        // load requested page
    }
}
```

The whole user validation thing is working just fine, but I now want to access the `user` object that was created during `page` construction.  Is this a possibility with the way I'm going about things, and if so, how do I access the `user` object?

Comment: Access it where? Outside of `page` class? Please be more specific.

Comment: As far as I know PHP does not support nesting classes.

Comment: Sorry yes, when I say access it, I mean outside of the `page` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, this a a pretty *moot* design. Better would be creating the user object outside of the page context then "injecting" it where needed:

```
# page.php
class Page {
    # private $_user; # maybe ... probably not needed.
    public function __construct( User $user ) {
        if ( $user->isLoggedIn() ) { /* etc */ }
        # if this will be needed in other functions, save a copy of the
        # obj reference to as an object attribute:
        $this->_user = $user;
    }
}

# user.php
class User {
    public function isLoggedIn() { /* etc */ }
}

# request_controller.php
$user = new User();
$page = new Page( $user );
```

Basically, avoid initiating classes from inside of object methods. This lead to non maintainable and non testable code. Especially when you'll need to "mock" the instances with mock services. I'd recommend you rethink the design, the one you have will only get smellier with time.

Comment: +1 Especially since the page doesn't have an obvious owning relationship :)

Comment: This is actually a sane suggestion. This code follows important OOP designs principles like DI, SRP and makes your code less dependent and coupled. +1

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  The only reason I did it the way I have was because I was trying to put as much code relating to generating the page into the `page` class, and validating the user is part of that process.  I'll rethink my design based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I can put `user` as an instance variable and then access it with the keyword `$this->`

example:

```
class Page {
    public $user; // private if you want to access it only within Page

    public function __contruct() {
        $this->user = new user();
        // rest of your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't advise people to expose class variables without good reason, it's bad practice. Use encapsulation where and whenever possible.

Comment: If you can pardon my ignorance/noobiness, please can you explain whether this is an acceptable approach to be using?

Comment: as Remco said it is bad practice... but it works. You should generally avoid bad practice. Take a look at smassey answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require_once 'classes/user.class.php';
class page {
    private $myUser;

    public function __construct() {
        // check user is logged in

        $this->myUser = new user();
        if(!$this->myUser->isLoggedIn()) {
            // user is not logged in
            // load login page
        }
        else {
            // user is logged in
            // load requested page
        }       
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->myUser;
    }
}

$p = new page();

$user = $p->getUser();
?>
```

Should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the object in the session and then access it anywhere.

Comment: Session is used to store information between two or more communicating devices or between computer and user. Its not a persistent storage for object or object data, and advocating using it as so is wrong. There are databases, memory cache and etc that used to persist objects. Please avoid storing object in session just to be able to _access it anywhere_.